# desire2learn simple PUT update in PHP

Tags: php, desire2learn

I am trying to update profile information in D2L Valence. I have been successful in downloading information using GET requests. But I am unsure how to format my requests in order to complete a simple update.

In this case I have downloaded a copy of a profile json block and changed the nickname field. Don't mind the d2l class called on the first line. It gets the json profile block, then I alter it and if I print it out then, I get

```
{"Nickname":"Johnny","Birthday":null,"HomeTown":"","Email":"","HomePage":"","HomePhone":null,"BusinessPhone":null,"MobilePhone":null,"FaxNumber":null,"Address1":null,"Address2":null,"City":null,"Province":null,"PostalCode":null,"Country":null,"Company":null,"JobTitle":"","HighSchool":null,"University":null,"Hobbies":"","FavMusic":"","FavTVShows":"","FavMovies":"","FavBooks":"","FavQuotations":"","FavWebSites":"","FutureGoals":"","FavMemory":"","SocialMediaUrls":[{"Name":"Facebook","Url":""},{"Name":"Twitter","Url":""},{"Name":"Google+","Url":""},{"Name":"LinkedIn","Url":""}]}
```

This is my PHP

```
$output = d2l::get_user_profile($usercontext,"real_profile_id",true);
$output = str_replace("\"Nickname\":\"\"", "\"Nickname\":\"Johnny\"",$output);  
$random_hash = md5(date('r', time()));          

$url = $usercontext->createAuthenticatedUri("/d2l/api/lp/1.1/profile/real_profile_id","PUT");
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("HTTP/1.1", "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=".$random_hash));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$output);       
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, '/var/www/cacert.pem');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
print_r(curl_getinfo($ch))
```

From this code, I get this response

```
Array
(
[url] => https://myurl.edu:443/d2l/api/lp/1.1/profile/myProfile?x_a=mykey&x_c=mykey&x_d=mykey&x_t=1349798248
[content_type] => text/html; charset=utf-8
[http_code] => 403
[header_size] => 218
[request_size] => 941
[filetime] => -1
[ssl_verify_result] => 20
[redirect_count] => 0
[total_time] => 0.171832
[namelookup_time] => 1.9E-5
[connect_time] => 0.033028
[pretransfer_time] => 0.105724
[size_upload] => 582
[size_download] => 13
[speed_download] => 75
[speed_upload] => 3387
[download_content_length] => 13
[upload_content_length] => 0
[starttransfer_time] => 0.171811
[redirect_time] => 0
[request_header] => POST /d2l/api/lp/1.1/profile/myProfile?x_a=mykey&x_c=mykey&x_d=mykey&x_t=1349798248 HTTP/1.1
Host: myurl.edu
Accept: */*
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=95b842a110e529794822be6870f2585c
Content-Length: 582


)
```

I've probably missed something obvious. Please advise or point me in the right direction.

Comment: I've tried to push around the contenttype and such. changing the headers to

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("HTTP/1.1", "Content-Type: application/json"));`

Doesn't help

Comment: changing the CURLOPT_POST to CURLOPT_PUT changes the http code to 302 since the docs say that updating the profile is a PUT not a POST.

Comment: I've solved the problem (after 2 days work) I'll post the answer as soon as SO lets me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a block of PHP code that works for doing an update, for anyone else who needs it.

$data is a string the text of the json

$opContext is a valid user context created with $authContext->createUserContext().

$url is the REST path you want to send to

I do realize there is an issue with

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

But I am living with it for the moment.

Here is the code

```
$putData = fopen('php://temp/maxmemory:256000', 'w');  
if (!$putData) {  
    die('could not open temp memory data');  
}  
fwrite($putData, $data);  
fseek($putData, 0);
$url = $opContext->createAuthenticatedUri($url,"PUT");
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("HTTP/1.1", "Content-Type: application/json"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE,$putData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, strlen($data));        
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);             
fclose($putData);
return $response;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have answered your own question in your followup comments, but the [myProfile update route](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/user.html#put--d2l-api-lp-%28D2LVERSION-version%29-profile-myProfile) uses an HTTP PUT not a POST: this is generally the case with most of the Valence APIs (create routes use POST and update routes use PUT).

Comment: Yes, that was half my problem, the other half was how to format headers and such so that it would work with cURL. See my answer below to how I got it to work.

Comment: Your example is very useful! Would you object to D2L enhancing their documentation around the PHP sample with it?

Comment: That's fine! I have some other PHP samples that I've built into my d2l PHP class that might be helpful for others as well.